# I'd like to get into Wings of War / Glory but am confused where to start

Tags: wings-of-glory

I became aware of Wings of War / Glory when someone mentioned it as an inspiration for the Xwing Miniatures game. I'm late to the party and would like to understand the differences between Wings of War and Wings of Glory, other than branding.

Basically, **how do I get started with this game?**

A good answer would include details like:

- Can you combine both games or are the rules / materials different?
- Can you combine WWI and WWII versions of the game?
- Is there an ideal box to start with?
- Are all the new products with miniatures or is there an option to play with just cards?